# Деление на слоги в Python

Tags: python, словари, деление

Хотел написать программу которая будет делить слово в инпуте на слоги используя правила деления русского языка. Я пробовал писать наброски но все никак не могу подобрать действующий метод, подскажите кто программирует в питоне.

Comment: А что именно в питоне вам непонятно? Если у вас есть алгоритм, то что вам мешает его реализовать? Если у вас нет алгоритма, то при чём тут питон? Если у вас проблемы и с алгоритмом, и с питоном, то вопрос слишком общий — решать за вас не самую простую задачу целиком тут вряд ли кто-то будет

Comment: [Возможно, вам стоит посмотреть здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/405161/detecting-syllables-in-a-word)

Comment: можно словарь произношений использовать, чтобы слоги выделить: [Pig Latin Translator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22773826/4279)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Загуглил правило деления на слоги и на первой [ссылке](http://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/39-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_fonetika__slovoobrazovanie__morfologiya_i_orfografiya/stages/632-16_slog_pravila_perenosa_slov.html) получил вот такой вот алгоритм. Ну для начала как статичные данные поделим слагаемые и гласные и на два массива, а также пустую строчку для вывода. Создадим новый массив, элементы массива берутся из инпута, разделенные пробелами (метод str.split(' ')). Работаем с массивом слов: на слово делаем цикл и с каждой итерацией проверяем букву: согласная -> продолжаем до первой гласной, после проверяем следующую букву(ы): если [й], [р], [рь], [л], [ль], [м], [мь], [н], [нь], то склеиваем начальную согласную, гласную и последующую согласную(ые) и на конце добавляем дефис, заносим нашу комбинацию в изначально-созданную строку. Также рассмотрим случай, если закрытый слог на конце: (имеем уже согл+гл) проверяем, будет ли следующая итерация последней если да, то склеиваем с имеющейся согл+гл и получаем согл+гл+согл, но т.к. итерация последняя (в условии склеивания с "-" добавить проверку на последнюю итерацию), то '-' не приклеиваем к нашей комбинации, а добавляем пробел(так же при последней итерации массива слов укажем, что пробел не добавляется). Алсо можно слова не склеивать со строкой сразу, а добавлять их в ещё один массив(уже делённые на слога). После методом с циклом внутри str.join(цикл для массива разделенных слога слов) склеить за раз. Вроде как понятно объяснил если что, то могу написать, когда будет время. Успехов!

Answer (score -2):

1. Делаешь массив гласные и согласные
   *glasnie = [а,е,и,й, итд]
   soglasnie = [б,в,г,д, итд]*
2. дальше указываешь длину строки
   *str_end = 100*
3. определяешь длину input строки

   ```
   if len(s)<= str_end:

      print(s)  
   else:

      split = s.split()
   ```

разбиваем на слова
   и через цикл суммируешь слова, пока не достигнут 100 символов, если достигнет, тогда уже разбиваешь слово посимвольно и делаешь перенос используя массивы гласных и согласных.

в помощь https://pythonworld.ru/tipy-dannyx-v-python/stroki-funkcii-i-metody-strok.html

Comment: Задача была разделить слово на слоги. А у вас о чем?

Comment: я так понял, ему надо перенос слова по слогам в конце строки. если нет, тогда еще проще.

Comment: Hадо написать программу которая будет разделять одно слово на слоги